# javascript: adding form on click

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to add new input form by clicking on a button.
The form that I have and I would like to add:

```
<input type="number" id="portdiv" name="ports" min="0" max="48" size="1"/>
```

The button to add the new form:

```
<input type="button" value="Add another" onClick="addInput('portdiv');"/>
```

The javascript function:

```
var counter = 1;
function addInput(divName){
var textbox = document.createElement('input');
textbox.type = 'number';
document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(textbox);
counter++;
}
```

This code do not works and I have not any errors on javascript console. 
I have have tried different solution for the javascript function:

```
    var textbox = document.createElement('input');
    textbox.type = 'text';
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(textbox);
    counter++;
```

AND

```
      var newFields = document.getElementById(divName).cloneNode(true);
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newFields);
      counter++;
```

Nobody of them works. How can be solved?

Comment: There are many blank parts here, like the initial HTML. Can you reproduce your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: The problem is present in fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BByfD/). What must I add?

Comment: I combined @epascarello 's answer with a correct wrapping (see menu at left). [Voilà](http://jsfiddle.net/UbdFZ/)

Comment: @user1382278 You need to add it to the parent element, not the input! Your code says a div, but you have are passing in an input's id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to append an input to a input! An input does not have child elements.

You need to append it to the parent element that holds the form elements. By the name of your variable it would be some sort of div element. You can either do it by the name of the div, or use [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).

Comment: And I thought the `div` HTML was missing... didn't see that the input had this id. +1. The problem might also be a duplicate id.

Comment: I love how I got a downvote for the right answer. I love stackoverflow